# php explode like function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, implode

I have a column in my database name location which have city name and country name in this format `New york,America`. I want to run a select query with the explode function like which we use in php to separate values like this
so that i can get comma , separated values

```
select explode(",",location) from address;
```

Also with the alias of city column holding New York and alias of country holding value of America. So that i can use them in my store procedure and insert this values in references table in the columns city and country

Comment: Separate? Or join? Your value is joined in the table already unless I am reading this wrong ("I have a column").

Comment: I'm thinking you are looking for the explode variant of PHP. Not implode

Comment: In php we use `explode()` function to sepArate values

Comment: @JayBlanchard i want it to seperate

Comment: You want to separate it *into what*?! MySQL doesn't have arrays, so what would the expected result be?

Comment: @deceze i want them to use in store procedure so that i can store these value in other table

Comment: Update your question to clarify that; be specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @deceze i have updated it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: @vp_arth this the solution for the SqlServer i want this for mysql

Comment: are you developer? can't you write your own use this logic?... See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not really "explode" or split on *all* comma's, but you can split a string on *any* comma using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('New york,America', ',', 1);
-> New york
```

Comment: I want to split Colum values not a string @Sjoerd

Comment: @usama, what difference? it's just sql function.

Comment: @vp_arth the difference is i want to select city,country from location colum and store this into the other table colums city and country using store procedure

Comment: no any difference in your example) just use `substring_index` function 2 times, for city and for country.

Comment: @Sjoerd with i can get the New york but witj index 2 SUBSTRING_INDEX('New york,America', ',', 2) it return both New york,America

Comment: try `-1` index instead of `2`. It will mean: `all, after last comma`

Answer (score 1):

Use Group concat

```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( location )
    FROM `address`
```

Comment: Read the comments under the question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see the comments.

Comment: @Suraj can you help me what will be the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION strSplit(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), pos int)  
returns varchar(255)
return replace(substring(
  substring_index(x, delim, pos+1), 
  length(substring_index(x, delim, pos)) + 1
), delim, '');


select strSplit("aaa,b,cc,d", ',', 1) as second;
> b
```

Comment: where should i define this function in my store procedure so that i can use it

Comment: and you always can to use return statement of this function directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the row and store it as a string, and use the **explode** function to separate the values if you are intending to use the function itself.

Comment: i want this to work in mysql store procedure not in php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that exploding will be to create N number of rows, then you can do it like this.

```
SET @completeString = "Hola,New york,America,!,";
SET @divider = ",";

WITH RECURSIVE strings(m) AS (
    SELECT
        @completeString
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(m, INSTR(m, @divider)+ 1)
    FROM
        strings
    WHERE
        INSTR(m, @divider)!= 0
)
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(m, @divider, 1) exploted_strings
FROM
    strings;
```

That'll give you five rows, including the empty string

```
+----------------+
|exploted_strings|
+----------------+
| Hola           |
| New york       |
| America        |
| !              |
|                |
+----------------+
```

Or have it in a Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE explode(IN completeString TEXT, IN divider TEXT)
BEGIN
    WITH RECURSIVE strings(m) AS (
        SELECT 
            completeString
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(m, INSTR(m, divider)+ 1)
        FROM 
            strings 
        WHERE 
            INSTR(m, divider)!= 0
)
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(m, divider, 1)
    FROM strings;
END
```

And call it like

```
CALL explode ("Hola,New york,America,!,",",");
```